# Where to put the .vimrc file for sudo in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editor, vi

I always put a .vimrc in my home folder for turning `:syntax on`. But in OS X Lion it seems that `sudo vi foo.txt` ignore or can't find this vim configuration anymore.

Has anyone experiences the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing **sudo visudo** and making sure that this lines appears somewhere in there:

```
Defaults  env_keep += "HOME"
```

This should maintain the **HOME** directory and **~** should would as it did in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have use the same .vimrc and .vim folders as my main users and link them to a safe backupped place on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) - wich btw is awesome for this kind of task.

The location of the home folder for your su is `/var/root`. Therefore .vimrc and the .vim folder belong there.

Comment: Thanks, good idea! :) Would like to mark your answer as correct, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vim` instead of vi.  Sometimes the default for "vi" is compatibility mode.  Not sure if this is the case with Lion, however.